# Binding Itemscontrol item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My XAML is as under. I have a main ViewModel which has a list of items and I want to display a property within this list

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding MyName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"></Label>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem is that MyName is always blank although my list has two items.

The main VM class has this property below and I add items in the constructor

```
public ObservableCollection<InnerViewModel> MyList { get; set; }
```

My inner VM has

```
public class InnerViewModel 
{
    private string _MyName;
    public string MyName 
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyName;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyName");
        }
    }
```

I do have OnPropertyChanged in place but I'm not pasting it here for simplicity. I think the problem is with the XAML but I'm not sure. How do I get the property MyName to be displayed in my list of items in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and remove the relative source part of the binding.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Label Content="{Binding MyName}"></Label>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That works. Thanks but please explain in two lines that why should RelativeSource not work?

Comment: Because of the context. When you are using data templates the context of the binding is an item of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Since you use `MyList` as the `ItemsSource`, the data source for the child elements will be `MyList`. So you do not need to use the RelativeSource.

In other words, this should work :

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding MyName}"></Label>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```